# React Router 6 Nest Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a protected route that wraps my layout route for my other components that uses the layout component.

Im having an issue with the protected route not working as expected. If a user is null, when I try to access **localhost:3000/create** for example it should render my landing page but instead I get a blank screen.

I realized that if I only have one route that contains one element prop it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

## My Routes

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
      <Route element={<ResponsiveDrawer />}>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/create' element={<Create />} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' element={<Edit />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

## My Protected Routes

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
 const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
 // console.log(user);

 return user !== null ? <Outlet /> : <LandingPage />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ProtectedRoutes` is rendering an `Outlet` component for nested `Route` components to be rendered into. The `ResponsiveDrawer` also needs to render an `Outlet` for any nested `Route` components it is wrapping.

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>    // <-- render Outlet
      <Route element={<ResponsiveDrawer />}> // <-- render Outlet
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/create' element={<Create />} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' element={<Edit />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

The route rendering the `ResponsiveDrawer` is rendered into the `ProtectedRoutes` component's `Outlet`, and nested routes are rendered into the `ResponsiveDrawer` component's `Outlet`.

Example `ResponsiveDrawer`:

```
const ResponsiveDrawer = () => {
  // business logic

  return (
    <>
      {/* UI */}
      {/* Drawer UI */}
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I did use an Outlet component in my ResponsiveDrawer. The issue is my ProtectedRoutes is not working. When i try to access a path  eg: localhost:3000/dashboard from my landing page, any unauthorised user shouldn't be able to access that page and should be redirected back to my landing page to login. At the minute, when i access the dashboard page without logging in, it shows me a blank page. Perhaps nesting a Route component with an element prop is causing the problem?

Comment: @HenryDinh I see. No, that should all work. Can you edit your post to include all the relevant code you are working with? The `UserContext` that the `PrivateRoutes` component uses and the `ResponsiveDrawer` component?

Comment: I think my user context was creating the issue. I tried setting the user to localStorage after they login and remove it after the user logs out. This works right now but im not sure if this is the proper way of doing it. Im still new to react and learning as i go

Comment: @HenryDinh No worries. Using localStorage to persist React state is a common pattern.

Comment: Thanks Drew. So far so good =)